# Login with Django doesn't work (?csrfmiddlewaretoken)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django project and I'm working on login form. I have problem, login doesn't go through, page is refreshed and not logged in. I have created login form but I wanted to move from (this part has worked)

```
    <form action="{% url 'learning_app:login' %}" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
```

I wanted to remove `{{ form.as_p }}` to apply styling of my liking, and I have done it like this...

```
<!-- Form Input -->
<form action="{% url 'learning_app:login' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- Form Input --> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p class="p-sm input-header">Username</p>
      <input class="form-control email" type="username" name="username"> 
    </div>

    <!-- Form Input --> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p class="p-sm input-header">Password</p>
      <div class="wrap-input">
        <span class="btn-show-pass ico-20"><span class="flaticon-visibility eye-pass"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control password" type="password" name="password"> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form Submit Button --> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn--theme hover--theme submit">Log In</button>
    </div> 

  </form>
```

this is forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

This is urls.py

```
app_name = 'learning_app'

urlpatterns = [
    #home
    path('', views.home, name='home'), 

    # login / logout urls
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    
    #dashboard
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

Also, I have added this to settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'learning_app:dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = 'learning_app:login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'learning_app:logout'
```

When I put login credentials, page is refreshed and I have this link in my browser...

http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=uWSaZ591vCPC4A0DEKC0KuoaCGHbGz15gVDbfRozzt3OjpN86bGdJbwS93b156fq&username=cool_username&password=wR7XR7RFMisfD4s&next=

I have done everything by instructions but it seems that it doesn't go through. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like it does not take the `method="post"` can you share the *rendered* form?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I don't have anything in views regarding this, if you are thinking about that

Comment: so if you visit the `/login` page, what HTML does the browser get?

Comment: It gets `registration/login.html` with login form. I don't think anything else

Comment: Add `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />` to the form.  You have it on the first, but not the second html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, I had two form HTML tags, when I removed one - it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your settings configuration is wrong. It should either look like this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ''
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login/'
LOGIN_URL = 'login/'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout/'
```

or maybe try:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('learning_app:dashboard')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('learning_app:login')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('learning_app:login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('learning_app:logout')
```

Also, it seems that your POST request is not being correctly processed. Try writing it
CAPITALIZED